# Format Change in SAS

Tags: format, sas

I know how to change the format of variables through data step like following.

```
data want;
  set have;
  format abc date9.;
run;
```

But if the format change requires converting from Character to Numeric then to Date involves following code with **creation of new variable** which I want to avoid.

```
data want;
  set have;
  abc_1 = input(scan(abc,"1"),ddmmyy10.);
  format abc_1 date9.;
run;
```

Is it possible to avoid creation of new variable and change **Character** into **Numeric** and then **Date9.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cause a character variable to contain the `DATE9.` formatted date value, but you can't have it contain the underlying date value and show a format, no.

```
abc = put(input(scan(abc,'1'),ddmmyy10.),date9.);
```

However, it won't be a numeric with a date format.  To do that, you have to create a new variable.  You can cause it to be written to the dataset with the same name;

```
data want;
  set have;
  abc_1 = input(scan(abc,"1"),ddmmyy10.);
  format abc_1 date9.;
  drop abc;
  rename abc_1=abc;
run;
```

but it still technically creates a new variable (even though you don't really see that in the output).